# Laravel, How to redirect to different login page if not login

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using editor middleware and customer middleware, I want to redirect every one to a different login page if not login

so for editor if anyone tried to open editor/dashboard then redirect to editor/login route and if tried to open customer dashboard then return to customer/login

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:web','editor'],'prefix' => 'editor'], function () {

Route::get('/dashboard', 'Editor\EditorController@index');
```

Middleware:

Customer:

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
    if((auth()->user()->role_id == 3)AND(auth()->user()->status == 1)){
      return $next($request);   
                    }return redirect()->intended('/')->withSuccess('You do not have access permission to Customer dashboard');
 }
```

Editor:

```
  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
    if((auth()->user()->role_id == 3)AND(auth()->user()->status == 1)){
      return $next($request);   
                   }
    return redirect()->intended('/')->withSuccess('You do not have access permission to Editor pages'); }
```

Comment: please put your middleware code

Answer (score 0):

add in you `editor` middleware

```php
 if(is_null(auth()->user())){
            return redirect('editor/login')
 }
 return $next($request);
```

Comment: it will apply on for those route which is use this middlware and make sure your auth middleware should not apply

Answer (score 0):

```
//Customer

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(auth()->user() && (auth()->user()->role_id == CUSTOMER_ROLE_ID) && (auth()->guard('user')->user()->status == 1)) {
      return $next($request);   
    } 
    return redirect()->intended('login/customer')->withSuccess('You do not have access permission to Editor pages');
} 

//Editor
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(auth()->user() && (auth()->user()->role_id == EDITOR_ROLE_ID) && (auth()->guard('user')->user()->status == 1)) {
      return $next($request);   
    }
    return redirect()->intended('login/editor')->withSuccess('You do not have access permission to Editor pages');
}
```

Comment: Im asking about if he is not login, I mean if he copied editor/dashboard and tried to open it in other browser!!

Comment: you may add auth()->user() in if statement to check if user already authenticated
Check updated answer

Comment: can you add it in ur answer? I tried this but stil back me to login page

Comment: Added it to my answer

Comment: nothing changed, still redirect me to the normal login page, I want it if this route in the editor middleware group then if the user is not login to redirect him to editor login page

Answer (score 0):

```
//customer
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
 {
   if(auth()->guard('user')->user()->role_id == 3 && auth()->guard('user')->user()->status == 1){
     return $next($request);   
   }
   return redirect("/");
} 

//editor
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
 {
   if(auth()->guard('user')->user()->role_id == 3 && auth()->guard('user')->user()->status == 1){
     return $next($request);   
    }
   return redirect("/"); 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's good to provide code snippet as solutions, but code-only answers are considered bad practice. Please elaborate what this snippet does and how it fixes the problem.

Comment: where is the different of what you wrote and what I have??????????